# Why did Eve Believe the Snake?

Tags: theology, gan-eden

Rashi in Genesis 3 states:

> כָּל אֻמָּן שׂוֹנֵא אֶת בְּנֵי אֻמָּנוּתוֹ, מִן הָעֵץ אָכַל וּבָרָא אֶת הָעוֹלָם (בראשית רבה):
> כי ידע FOR [GOD] KNOWS — Every artisan detests his fellow-artisans (“Two of a trade never agree”). The serpent suggested to her: God ate of the tree and created the world (Genesis Rabbah 19:4) so if you eat ...

Why did Eve believe the snake? How could she now feel that God, before being able to create, was a creature in a place with the tree, and yet credit God (after God ate from the fruit) for creating the world that contains that tree?!!! Sounds like Back to the Future!!

Did she believe that the tree preexisted  the world and that God as a creature encountered the tree and ate from it and then was capable of and indeed created the world around it?

Comment: I recall a medrash that says that she said "we will die if we touch the tree" and the snake pushed her into it and she didn't die. So once the snake "proved" himself right, anything he said would have extra credence attached to it.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Maskil_LeDavid%2C_Genesis.3.5.1?lang=bi

Comment: אילת השחר בראשית פרק ג פסוק ה (פרשת בראשית)
(ה) כי ידע אלקים. פרש"י כל אומן שונא את בני אומנתו מן העץ אכל וברא את העולם. והנה אם חוה היתה מתבוננת בדבריו היתה מבינה שזה שטות דע"כ שה' ברא את העץ הזה, ואיך אומר שע"י שאכל מהעץ הוא ברא את העולם, אלא שזה דרך היצה"ר שמעוור את עיני האדם בטענות הבל,

Comment: תורת חיים מסכת סנהדרין דף לח עמוד ב
 וכיון שהאמין לדברים בטלים הללו נמצא שהיה סבור שהעולם קדמון ח"ו שהרי סבור היה שהעץ קדמון הוא אם כן באכילת העץ היה כופר בעיקר שלא האמין שהוא יתברך עיקר ויסוד הכל.

Comment: של"ה פרשת קרח תורה אור
 שהנחש כפר בחידוש העולם יש מאין רק יש מיש, כמו שאמר מן העץ הזה אכל וברא את העולם (בראשית רבה פי"ט ס"ד), והכופר בחידוש כופר במציאת השם יתברך,